# Calculate height of div element based on offsetHeight and clientHeight not working in Css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get the exact div height that contains certain elements within it, I have margins and padding associated with that div.
here HTML:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="child">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
    </p>
    <ul>
      <li>test</li>
      <li>test333</li>
    </ul>
    <p>
      <strong>testststststs</strong>
    </p>

  </div>
 
</div>
```

css:

```
.main {
  display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.child{

   margin: 10px 10px 10px 25px;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 16px;
    
}
```

Js:

```
var cont = document.getElementsByClassName('main-class')[0];
var child = cont.getElementsByClassName('child')[0];
console.log(cont.clientHeight); //60
console.log(child.clientHeight);//40
console.log(child.offsetHeight);//40
```

i'm not sure if im getting the correct height for the child as the height seems to be lesser than the parent height- if that is the case why would it truncated as shown here:
https://jsfiddle.net/cudwb2yz/

I want to get the entire height of the `div- child` document including the content that has been hidden with the `overflow:hidden` property.
any idea what im doing wrong?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, then you need `scrollHeight`

Comment: omg yes that worked- thanks much

Comment: no problem. Glad to help.